# How to call batch from powershell so I can see realtime output in powershell console

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I need to call batch from powershell with specific working directory. I don't want new console to be opened, but I would like to see the output of the batch as a part of the output from powershell script.

I could forward the standard output to file and then write it by Write-Host, but the batch takes time and I would like to see the output in realtime as it is processing.

I tried Process-Start, but I don't know how to redirect standard output of batch to standard output of powershell.

Comment: Just call your batch with a `&`. Example: `& "c:\yourbatch.bat"`

Comment: @jisaak: And how I set different working directory?

Comment: You could read the current location using `get-location`, store that in a variable, change the working dir, call the script and finally set the previous location back. For example:  `$wd = Get-Location; Set-Location "you working dir"; & "Your batch"; Set-Location $wd`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add 'cmd /c ' to your ps script, and to change directories, you can use @jisaak suggestion, so:

```
$wd = Get-Location;
Set-Location "batch file directory";
cmd /c "Your batch";
Set-Location $wd;
```

That will open a new cmd in the current console and all the output will be directed to it(when the batch will reach EOF the cmd terminates).